# How to open a User Control in UWP

Tags: uwp, user-controls, visibility

I can't seem to find a method for the Usercontrol class that allows you to open a user control.

I know if you use windows Forms or WPF, you can use the Usercontrol.show() method, however UWP does not have a Usercontrol.show() method or anything equivalent to that.

I have also tried setting the visibility to visible and that does not work either

Here is the Usercontrol UWP class documentation [Usercontrol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=winrt-19041)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, you can understand `UserControl` as a container in which some controls are placed.

For a control container, the way to display it on the interface is to put it in the visual tree.

`UserControl` does not have a **Show** method. To show it, you can do this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <MyUserControl .../>
</Grid>
```

or add it in code-behind

```cs
RootGrid.Children.Add(new MyUserControl());
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, mostly does what I needed it to do. In WPF and Win Forms, I was able to get the user control to open in a new window, however since we are displaying the user control in its own grid on the main window, kinda messes up the design of the program. Hence how do we open the user control in a new window.

Comment: Hello, if you want to open a new window in UWP, you can check this document: [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views), you can achieve your goal by placing the UserControl on a page, and then navigating to the page in the frame of the new window.